# how to paste values in excel without overwriting existing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column **Date** which already has values inside like 03/01/1990 now from another sheet I want to copy time and paste it in  same cell. 13/01/1990 21:00:03 . I have 2000 entries how can I paste time here with out overwriting date. there should be space between time and date? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use a helper colum, add together then paste values into the original column.

Comment: Probably you could benefit from [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) or concatenating using Ampersand (&)

Answer (score 1):

You can just sum the two columns. By default, a date has a time equals 00:00:00. So if you add 21:00:03 with 03/01/1990 you'll obtain 03/01/1990 21:00:03. in the sum column you just need to make sure that the cell is in the format you want, like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Below is an image of the procedure.

[image: Illustration of the procedure described in excel]